# Single Publication With Multiple Subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication

What should I be aware of before adding multiple subscribers to single publication?

Obvious ones I can think of are **server capacity** and **network bandwidth**.

Should I be aware of anything else?

Comment: I do this type of replication all the time here at work. I would look at setting up a remote distributor to take some of that workload off of your OTLP database, assuming  it's a production database of course.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure distribution database is set up correctly with data and log file sizes based on the volume of data you are planning to replicate. I am not sure which version of SQL you are using, but i had issues when i was replicating from 1 publisher to 2 subscribers in SQL 2008 during re initialization. My issue was related to virtual memory being maxed out at one subscriber. It may not be applicable in your case.